# horizontal content

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is how to make dynamic content to be shown horizontally. It means no vertical scrolling, only horizontal. I have tried `-webkit-column-count` but it only creates X columns, but not horizontal scrolling. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show some sample code.

Comment: I have no code so I'm assking for suggestions.

Comment: Something like horizontal scrolling in Windows 8?

Comment: exactly like in store in apps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

But then you'll have to be careful about putting line breaks in where you want them otherwise you'll end up with one really long line of text. http://jsfiddle.net/Nbkj2/1/

Comment: just use a breaking tag like a br, p, or div, and that'll force a break.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty open-ended question, as I'm sure there's a lot of ways to answer this, but maybe this will point you in a useful direction: http://www.sitepoint.com/side-scrolling-site-layout-with-css-and-jquery/

To summarize the article, you break your content into a series of full-screen pages.  Each page is a div with CSS to take up the whole screen, with height/width properties and `float:left;` to make them all stack up sideways. To prevent the pages from wrapping you make the body of the document as wide as all the pages you've made: `body { width:10000px; }`

Then the author puts some javascript handlers on links to scroll the page sideways to each panel of content.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what element and what you mean by horizontal. Here's two examples of what I think you mean.

```
div { 
    Width:20%;
    Display:inline-block; //won't work for ie 8 and below
}
body {
    width: 150%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this demo (HTML add CSS only)

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/enve/ea88y/

FROM: http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/horizontal-website.php

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#one">ONE</a></li>
<li><a href="#two">TWO</a></li>
<li><a href="#three">THREE</a></li>
<li><a href="#four">FOUR</a></li>
<li><a href="#five">FIVE</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="wrap">
<div id="one"><p>ONE</p></div>
<div id="two"><p>TWO</p></div>
<div id="three"><p>THREE</p></div>
<div id="four"><p>FOUR</p></div>
<div id="five"><p>FIVE</p></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>​
```

**CSS**

```
 * {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
html {
height:100%;
overflow-x:scroll;
}
body {
height:100%;
}
#wrap {
min-height:100%;
width:500%;
overflow:hidden;
}
#one, #two, #three, #four, #five {
width:20%;
float:left;
}
ul {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:40px;
line-height:40px;
text-align:center;
background:#ccc;
}
li {
display:inline;
margin:0 50px;
}
p {
margin:50px;
text-align:center;
}
* html ul {position:absolute;left:expression(0+((e=document.documentElement.scrollLeft)?e:document.body.scrollLeft)+'px');} 
* html {background:url(fake.jpg)}
* html #full {height:100%;}​
```